# ggplot2: one graph up to current end, onwards multiple graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am intending to create a graph with ggplot2. It is supposed to show the past course of a time series of a varibale for the last five years up to the current end. I generated three different time series of point forecasts for the subsequent year by three different forecast methods. 
The graph I am thinking about reveals the past values in one color (black) and the three time series of point forecast in different colors.

This is my data and my approach:

```
ae<-ts(c(4.670958, 4.606170, 4.610158, 4.697749, 4.685828, 4.581902, 4.676560, 4.662495, 4.737951, 4.697749, 4.643429, 4.740575, 4.714921, 4.597138, 4.709530, 4.727388, 4.723842, 4.655863, 4.732684, 4.724729, 4.762174, 4.727388, 4.682131, 4.695011, 4.783316, 4.572647, 4.734443, 4.759607, 4.715817, 4.720283, 4.719391, 4.714025, 4.843399, 4.758749, 4.682131, 4.841033, 4.783316, 4.603168, 4.735321, 4.751865, 4.761319, 4.719391, 4.689511, 4.742320, 4.834693, 4.763028, 4.704110, 4.821893, 4.703204, 4.660605, 4.752728, 4.734443, 4.789989, 4.830711, 4.758749, 4.771532, 4.935193, 4.728272, 4.809742, 4.838660, 4.763028), start=c(2012,7), frequency=12)   
af<-ts(c(4.735572, 4.786397, 4.794226, 4.847278, 4.828640, 4.831721, 4.828364, 4.917734, 4.843730, 4.817140, 4.907995, 4.846953), start=c(2017,8), frequency=12)
bf<-ts(c(4.731111, 4.802771, 4.789276, 4.855957, 4.787150, 4.839004, 4.815918, 4.910693, 4.831316, 4.804971, 4.894336, 4.837539), start=c(2017,8), frequency=12)    
cf<-ts(c(4.734454, 4.786685, 4.796952, 4.849983, 4.831067, 4.833924, 4.831631, 4.924311, 4.847889, 4.820325, 4.914030, 4.851841), start=c(2017,8), frequency=12)

month2<-seq(as.Date('2012-7-1'),to=as.Date('2018-7-1'),by='month')
al<-binder(window(ae, c(2012,7), c(2017,7)),af)
bl<-binder(window(ae, c(2012,7), c(2017,7)),bf)
cl<-binder(window(ae, c(2012,7), c(2017,7)),cf)
df2<-data.frame(month2,al,bl,cl)
meltdf <- reshape2::melt(df2,id="month2")
ggplot(meltdf,aes(x=month2,y=value,colour=variable,group=variable)) + geom_line()
```

I do not like this approach because past values have the same color as the last point forecast. What makes perfectly sense, because thats what the code says. Is there some way to make it better? This is what it looks like right now:

[image: 1]

Thanks a lot. 
Julia

Comment: Could you add required libraries I am unable to reproduce your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would simply treat the observed data and the forecast data as two separate bodies of data, each over a different timespan. Then you end up with two `data.frame`s, one for the observed, one for the forecasts. It would look something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

# OP's data
ae <- ts(c(4.670958, 4.606170, 4.610158, 4.697749, 4.685828, 4.581902,
           4.676560, 4.662495, 4.737951, 4.697749, 4.643429, 4.740575,
           4.714921, 4.597138, 4.709530, 4.727388, 4.723842, 4.655863,
           4.732684, 4.724729, 4.762174, 4.727388, 4.682131, 4.695011,
           4.783316, 4.572647, 4.734443, 4.759607, 4.715817, 4.720283,
           4.719391, 4.714025, 4.843399, 4.758749, 4.682131, 4.841033,
           4.783316, 4.603168, 4.735321, 4.751865, 4.761319, 4.719391,
           4.689511, 4.742320, 4.834693, 4.763028, 4.704110, 4.821893,
           4.703204, 4.660605, 4.752728, 4.734443, 4.789989, 4.830711,
           4.758749, 4.771532, 4.935193, 4.728272, 4.809742, 4.838660,
           4.763028),
         start=c(2012,7), frequency=12)   

af <- ts(c(4.735572, 4.786397, 4.794226, 4.847278, 4.828640, 4.831721,
           4.828364, 4.917734, 4.843730, 4.817140, 4.907995, 4.846953),
         start=c(2017,8), frequency=12)

bf <- ts(c(4.731111, 4.802771, 4.789276, 4.855957, 4.787150, 4.839004,
           4.815918, 4.910693, 4.831316, 4.804971, 4.894336, 4.837539),
         start=c(2017,8), frequency=12)    

cf <- ts(c(4.734454, 4.786685, 4.796952, 4.849983, 4.831067, 4.833924,
           4.831631, 4.924311, 4.847889, 4.820325, 4.914030, 4.851841),
         start=c(2017,8), frequency=12)

# Create separate month series, one for observed, one for forecasts
month1 <- seq(as.Date('2012-7-1'), to=as.Date('2017-7-1'), by='month')
month2 <- seq(as.Date('2017-8-1'), to=as.Date('2018-7-1'), by='month')

# data.frame for observed data
df1 <- data.frame(month=month1, dat=as.vector(ae))

# data.frame for forecast data with a label column to distinguish which
# forecast it is
df2 <- data.frame(month=month2, dat=as.vector(af), lab='a')
df3 <- data.frame(month=month2, dat=as.vector(bf), lab='b')
df4 <- data.frame(month=month2, dat=as.vector(cf), lab='c')
df_forcast <- rbind(df2, df3, df4)

# The plot then plots the data with two line geometries
ggplot(df1, aes(x=month, y=dat)) +
  geom_line() + # this plots the observed data
  geom_line(data=df_forcast, aes(col=lab)) # this plots the forecasts
```

The resulting graph will look like this:

[image: time series]

As you noted in your question, you need something in the actual data set you're plotting to indicate that different data points correspond to different things. There are, of course, other ways to accomplish that, but this approach gives you a lot of flexibility with how you visualize the final product.

(Note: there is a gap between the observed data and the forecasts; that is because the observed data end before the forecasts begin. If you want the lines to connect, you can simply duplicate the last data point of the observed data as the first data point of each forecast. That's an exercise I leave for you.)